# WebAPI Help Pages doesn't show all endpoints for OData controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, http-get, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I added Help Pages component for my ASP.NET MVC Web API with OData. To make it working I had to specify [ApiExplorerSetting(IgnoreAPI = false)] explicitly.

However, it shows default GET endpoint only, like: api/Customers.

But my API also supports GET by ID and some Navigation properties, like: api/Customers(id) and api/Customers(id)/ContactPerson

Is there a way to make Help Pages auto-generate those endpoints to?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HelpPage is really not supported for OData based controllers and that is the reason we explicitly set the `[ApiExplorerSetting(IgnoreAPI = true)]` attribute on `ODataController`. Even if you have tried making this setting to be `false`, it cannot be guaranteed that all the stuff(displaying all routes, samples generated) would work as expected, so I would suggest not to follow this approach.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the best approach in getting the documentation for OData? Any link will be appreciated.

Comment: Second that. I would love to be able to generate documentation for my OData endpoints.

Comment: Even I am looking for the same feature. We are currently developing the Odata WebApi services. We need to the help page documentation to share with QA automation team who cannot understand the metadata provided bare minimum details.